# Object ids in python data type

Tags: python

If I have a object in python that has a unique id such as

```
{"id":"123141222151",....}
```

What is the best data type for something like this? Should it be passed as a string or as an int? I was thinking string but I want to hear what others have to say about it.

Comment: A string is better for this because it allows you to have a common length for `id`s and also makes `id`s not subject to integer rules.

Comment: Where/how are these IDs getting generated? Are you only getting passed numeric data, such as a database index or counter-type value? Or is it arbitrary data?

Comment: Its numeric. It seems like logically its better to use string while operationally its better to use int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it is better to use int as it saves space,  also it is quicker when matching keys on integers than string.

Hope this helps